# Angular localization by culture

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization

I have successfully built an Angular internationalization project, however I want to do it now by culture, I mean not just es but es-AR or en-NZ.

Those are my configurations for Spanish and English in `angular.js` file:

```
"build": {
    ...
    "configurations": {
        ...
        "production-es": {
            "optimization": true,
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "outputPath": "dist/browser/es/",
            "sourceMap": false,
            "extractCss": true,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "aot": true,
            "extractLicenses": true,
            "vendorChunk": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }
            ],
            "baseHref": "/es/",
            "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.es.xlf",
            "i18nFormat": "xlf",
            "i18nLocale": "es",
            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
        },
        "production-en": {
            "optimization": true,
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "outputPath": "dist/browser/en/",
            "sourceMap": false,
            "extractCss": true,
            "namedChunks": false,
            "aot": true,
            "extractLicenses": true,
            "vendorChunk": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }
            ],
            "baseHref": "/en/",
            "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
            "i18nFormat": "xlf",
            "i18nLocale": "en",
            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
        }
    }
},
"serve": {
    ...
    "configurations": {
        ...
        "es": {
            "browserTarget": "i18n-demo:build:production-es"
        },
        "en": {
            "browserTarget": "i18n-demo:build:production-en"
        }
    }
}
```

What do I have to add for culture?
Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: The same thing you already did, but using `es-AR` instead of just `es`?

Answer (score 0):

After reading many articles, I found out that to localize the language by culture (country, or part of country) I need to change configuration. Instead of just using

```
"i18nLocale": "es",
```

in production for es, we have to use es-AR instead for Argentinian Spanish (for example). I tested it and it is working properly for me.
I also found out that it is automatically converts currencies and dates to the local format.